# Can jmap -histo trigger full garbage collection?

Tags: garbage-collection, jmap

We know that jmap -histo:live triggers a full gc in order to determine live objects:

[Does jmap force garbage collection when the live option is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418089/does-jmap-force-garbage-collection-when-the-live-option-is-used)

Since jmap -histo considers all objects in the heap (those in the young and old generation), my point is, jmap -histo can also trigger a full gc, too. However, I could not encounter a solid documentation about whether jmap -histo may trigger a full gc or not.

Can jmap -histo trigger full garbage collection?

Answer (score 9):

`jmap -histo`  will *not* trigger a full gc, but `jmap -histo:live` will.

Answer (score 7):

Someone with more JDK experience should verify this, but I'm fairly confident it does trigger full GC, at least in [OpenJDK 1.7](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7). Start with `jdk/src/share/classes/sun/tools/jmap/JMap.java`:

```
public class JMap {
    ...
    private static String LIVE_HISTO_OPTION = "-histo:live";
    ...        
    ...
      } else if (option.equals(LIVE_HISTO_OPTION)) {
            histo(pid, true);
    ...
    private static final String LIVE_OBJECTS_OPTION = "-live";
    private static final String ALL_OBJECTS_OPTION = "-all";
    private static void histo(String pid, boolean live) throws IOException {
        VirtualMachine vm = attach(pid);
        InputStream in = ((HotSpotVirtualMachine)vm).
            heapHisto(live ? LIVE_OBJECTS_OPTION : ALL_OBJECTS_OPTION);
        drain(vm, in);
    }
```

The ternary operator in `Jmap.histo()` makes a call to heapHisto in `jdk/src/share/classes/sun/tools/attach/HotSpotVirtualMachine.java` with the `-live` argument:

```
// Heap histogram (heap inspection in HotSpot)
public InputStream heapHisto(Object ... args) throws IOException {
    return executeCommand("inspectheap", args);
}
```

And if we look at `inspectheap` itself, in `hotspot/src/share/vm/services/attachListener.cpp`:

```
// Implementation of "inspectheap" command
//
// Input arguments :-
//   arg0: "-live" or "-all"
static jint heap_inspection(AttachOperation* op, outputStream* out) {
  bool live_objects_only = true;   // default is true to retain the behavior before this change is made
  const char* arg0 = op->arg(0);
  if (arg0 != NULL && (strlen(arg0) > 0)) {
    if (strcmp(arg0, "-all") != 0 && strcmp(arg0, "-live") != 0) {
      out->print_cr("Invalid argument to inspectheap operation: %s", arg0);
      return JNI_ERR;
    }
    live_objects_only = strcmp(arg0, "-live") == 0;
  }
  VM_GC_HeapInspection heapop(out, live_objects_only /* request full gc */, true /* need_prologue */);
  VMThread::execute(&heapop);
  return JNI_OK;
}
```

Note, in particular, the `live_objects_only` strcmp and the resulting `heapop` call two lines later. If `inspectheap` gets the `-live` argument via any avenue, it requests a full gc.

Answer (score 1):

No, `jmap -histo` will not trigger a FullGC. I am printing Histogram quite regularly and do not see any Full GCs in my GC logs.

I do not know how it is implemented in the VM but you do not need to worry about full GCs.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience:yes,it is.when you do this experiment,you can use the command:

```
 sudo -utomcat jstat -gcutil {PID} 1000 1000
```

description:
The first parameter 1000 after pid is time interval for print.
second parameter 1000 after pid is loop count.
use this command you can monitor the jvm gc activity.you can see the full gc time and count like below:

`S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
  0.00  18.45  13.12  84.23  47.64 206149 5781.308    83  115.479 5896.786
  0.00  21.84   5.64  84.24  47.64 206151 5781.358    83  115.479 5896.837
  0.00  32.27   1.66  84.24  47.64 206153 5781.409    83  115.479 5896.888
  0.00  13.96  53.54  84.24  47.64 206155 5781.450    83  115.479 5896.929
  0.00  21.56  91.77  84.24  47.64 206157 5781.496    83  115.479 5896.974`

and now you can execute the jmap command in other terminal,firstly,you execute the command without `:live` parameter and then execute it again with this parameter ,you should see a full gc activity when the command is executed with `;live` parameter , in other word , the full gc count will increment.

The second command maybe like this:

`sudo -u tomcat /home/path/to/jmap -histo:live {pid} | head -n 40`

By the way,my JDK version is JDK7