# Does JMAP lead to Full GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jmap

We have a WebLogic server with Java8 u172, I used "`jmap -heap $pid`" to check the heap memory usage, and then lead to Full GC every second. I waited for about 5 mins. It didn't stop. I can only try to `kill -9` and restart the server.

Does anyone know what happened?

Comment: It can do.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390665/can-jmap-histo-trigger-full-garbage-collection

Comment: `jmap -heap` does not trigger GC, though it causes a stop-the-world pause which may negatively impact on the application performance. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41738033/3448419