# How to force full gc on sun/oracle jvm, to perform memory alignment/compaction in old gen

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

I have a application that has a huge heap (around 100GB), and during initialization it allocates almost all avaliable memory with different caches. The  problem is that this initialization phase allocates lots of object that cause a painful de-fragmentation of old gen. So my idea is to force full gc as a last step of initialization phase to align/compact old gen and reduce probability of "Concurrent mode failure" in runtime.

Is there any way of forcing such a collection ?

Thanks

Comment: Well according to javadoc it does not guaranty that gc will fire.

Comment: I don't think anything guarantees this, but maybe I'm mistaken

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should run out of your memory and then call to `gc` should work.

Consider this way http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=19703

You can try also this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/6915221/1137529 but I am not sure if it will actually work fine.