# How do Java profilers work, internally?

Tags: java, jvm, profiling

I'm in the process of investigating how profilers work internally.

It seems there is an old API named [JVMPI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jvmpi/jvmpi.html), as well as a "new" API based on `java.lang.instrument`. I had the idea that profilers instrument all the classes' bytecode and insert hooks that call via sockets info to a given program's open-point, so establishing a communication with the profiler. Is this the standard approach? Do they differ considerably in approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, "[JVM TI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jvmti/) was introduced at JDK 5.0. JVM TI replaces the Java Virtual Machine Profiler Interface (JVMPI) and the Java Virtual Machine Debug Interface (JVMDI)." The standard profiler, [`jvisualvm`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html), uses the API extensively, for example to perform and monitor garbage collection, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14492574/230513). [Java Management Extensions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/jmx_connections.html) (JMX) is the common communications layer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on this, but it seems that JVMPI and JVMTI work differently.

- JVMPI seems to work by the agent processing "events" that the JVM emits when profiling is enabled.  It seems the event emitting logic is built into the JVM.
- JVMTI seems to work (for profiling) by having the agent inject bytecodes into the methods as they are loaded.

(This is from a brief read of the respective specs, as linked above.)