# Java closing/cleaning up

Tags: java, resources, release

I have a class that holds some big objects:

```
public class MyClass {

    BigObject bo;

    public MyClass() { ... }
}
```

Should i make a close method like the following:

```
public void close() {
    bo = null;
}
```

I think this is good for garbage collection (?) Am I on the right track? How should I approach the cleanup of this classes?

Comment: No, its unnecessary.  Just let it go out of scope.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481178/forcing-garbage-collection-in-java

Comment: in Java don't think about clean up of the objects.Java will handle it for you. You don't even have control on garbage collection part. However making object null can be good idea if you don't want any part of the software to access object anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think this is good for garbage collection

Nope, it just makes the code messier.

What's going to hold a reference to the instance of `MyClass`? If you genuinely need the instance of `MyClass` to stay alive, but not the `BigObject`, then - and only then - should you bother setting `bo` to null. But at the same time, you should also consider your design. Usually, all of the state of a class is important to it for its whole lifetime. There are exceptions to that rule, but they're relatively rare.

When the instance of `MyClass` is eligible for garbage collection, the value of its `bo` variable will be irrelevant to whether the instance of `BigObject` is eligible for garbage collection, so it doesn't matter whether or not it's been set to null... but it *does* make a big difference in terms of the amount of code you end up *not* having to write trying to manually clean up after yourself.

You should clean up resources such as streams, native handles etc - but generally you can let the garbage collector handle memory.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you lose the reference to the outer `MyClass` object, the inner `BigObject` reference is automatically understood to be uncreachable so it makes no difference to the Garbage Collector whether it is `null` or not. Do not clutter your codebase with such unnecessary code; write the code that fully leverages the benefits and services of the sophisticated garbage collection subsystem in Java.