# Android: how to force and wait GC for preparing memory before decoding large bitmap

Tags: android, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, dalvik

I am trapped with the OOM issue when I need to create large bitmap like 1920*1200 or even bigger. The program often crashes saying that DVM won't let me to allocate a bitmap of 9MB.

However, if I attach the program with DDMS and force GC before I create the bitmap, it works fine.

So I tried to call System.gc() in the decoding thread and even force the thread to sleep 1s for waiting the gc to happen. However, it never happens as I wished. Gc is still working in its own way.

So, could anybody tell me how to force GC to happen or is there any better way to deal with this case?

Update: I can see that I could just use DDMS to attach to the process and the GC will happen in real time. And it is working very well, no OOM ever. How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: it's not an answer, but I've read somewhere that you can allocate more than the limit through NDK.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I already know this. But what I need is to create a Bitmap object on Java side.

Comment: what about that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6915221/2075875 ?

Comment: No help, but still thanks.