# How can I delete a specific object?

Tags: java, object, garbage-collection, garbage

How can I manually delete a specific object before the garbage collector would ever collect it ?
For example I want to delete `requestToken` object. How can I do that ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481178/forcing-garbage-collection-in-java

Comment: You don't delete the object. The GC will.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't, and that you don't need to.  The GC will reclaim the memory when it needs to ... and there is no reason to interfere with that.

The only situation I can think of for *needing* to delete an object sooner is when the object contains information that needs to be erased ... for information security reasons.  (The classic example is when you are processing a password provided by the user and you are worried that it might leak via a code dump or something)  In that case, you need to implement a method on your object for erasing the object's fields by overwriting them.  But this requires careful design; e.g. to make sure that you find and erase all traces of the information.

It is also sometimes necessary to "help" the GC a bit to avoid potential memory leaks.  A classic example of this is the `ArrayList` class, which uses a Java array to represent the list content.  The array is often larger than the list's logical size, and the elements of the array *could* contain pointers to objects that have been removed from the list.  The `ArrayList` class deals with this by assigning `null` to these elements.

Note that neither of these examples involve actually deleting objects.  In both cases, the problem / issue is addressed another way.

---

It is also worth noting that calling `System.gc()` is usually a bad idea:

- It is not guaranteed to do anything at all.
- In most situations, it won't do anything that wouldn't happen anyway.
- In most situations, it is inefficient.  The JVM is in a better position than application code to know the ergonomically most efficient time to run the GC.  (Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2414621/139985) for a first-principles explanation of the ergonomics.)

The only cases where running the GC in production code is advisable are when you are trying to manage GC pauses, and you *know* that a pause is acceptable at a particular point in time.  (For example, when you are changing levels in an interactive game ... )

Comment: +1 Good, thorough answer.

Comment: One minor detail about `System.gc()`: On Android it does need to be called under certain circumstances to reclaim storage used for image data, etc.  But of course Android is not Java.

Comment: @HotLicks - yea.  What is going on there is that the Android platform is relying on finalization to free up native resources associated with images.  But that's arguably an application bug.  The app should be calling the dispose or delete or whatever method on the image.  (Just like you should `close()` files ....)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot delete an object, you can just try to make it eligible for garbage collection in its next cycle. The best you could do is , set the object as `null` and try calling `System.gc();`

Note: `System.gc()`  call will only request the JVM to run garbage collector but it cannot force it to.

Comment: You don't set objects to `null`, you set references to `null`.  And calling `System.gc()` usually worthless.

Comment: @HotLicks What is the ambiguity between setting the object to null or setting the reference to null in Java?

Comment: The "ambiguity" is that there is a very important difference between an *object* and a *reference*.