# How can I clean a static variable of a 3rd party library in Java

Tags: java, memory-management, singleton

I'm using a third library in Java which a uses a singleton pattern.
After using this library for a short time I no longer need this library and ready to free it, but because it uses a singleton pattern and doesn't supply any clean/free/close method which cleanup the allocated memory will keep in the heap as long as my application is running.

My question is: can I clean memory that was allocated for this library even if it doesn't supply any function for this?

Comment: In general, no. Are you able to run the library code in a separate process, so that all of the memory would be cleaned up when that terminates?

Comment: @AndyTurner, just want to know, why no? so, even let say, i set the reference to null, the reference will still not be able to be cleaned by gc?

Comment: @kucing_terbang In answer to the question "can *I* clean memory", no. You can't force the memory to be reclaimed by GC. You can't even guarantee that it can *ever* be reclaimed by GC, since the library might hold on to references that you can't see.

Comment: you can try and use refelection to get the "instance"-field of the singleton, make it accessible and assign "null":

  Field f = MailManager.class.getDeclaredField("instance");
  f.setAccessible(true);
  f.set(null, null);

Comment: @AndyTurner hmmm. Interesting.. do you have a reference to what you said? maybe a link to a doc or your experiment? that would be great.

Comment: Using reflection as @fiffy says can help in this?

Comment: @kucing_terbang I don't really know what you're looking for.  It is [well known](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481178/forcing-garbage-collection-in-java) that you can't really force a garbage collection, only hint that you'd like one; and how can you know all of the references held by the library that you'd need to null out in order to allow them to be GC'd?

Comment: @AndyTurner ouch, I think we are not on the same page here. I thought you were talking about the gc cannot clean up an object that which has no reference anymore.