# Java finalize() method is not called after using gc() method?

Tags: java

To see the working of `finalize()` method in java which is called when the object is about to be destroyed, I have wrote the following program

```
class counterTest{
    public static int count;
    public counterTest(){
        count++;
    }
}

public class finalize {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        counterTest obj1=new counterTest();
        System.out.println("Number of objects :" + counterTest.count);
        counterTest obj2=new counterTest();
        System.out.println("Number of objects :" + counterTest.count);
        Runtime rs=Runtime.getRuntime();
        obj1=null;
        obj2=null;
        rs.gc();
    }
    protected void finalize(){
        System.out.println("Program about to terminate");
        counterTest.count--;
        System.out.println("Number of objects :" + counterTest.count);
    }
}
```

I expected the output to be like this

```
Number of objects :1 
Number of objects :2 
Program about to terminate 
Number of objects :1 
Program about to terminate 
Number of objects :0
```

But I am just getting the first two lines. Since I am making the objects references to null and then calling the `gc()` method, I expect that the statements written in inside `finalize()` method should be displayed. Does this mean there is no guarantee that `finalize()` method will be called each time we have used `gc()` method.

Comment: Calling gc does not guarantee finalize execution, but it just suggests.

Comment: @Sai Have a look to [java code convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force garbage collection in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481178/how-to-force-garbage-collection-in-java)

Comment: Have a look at **J. Bloch's "Effective Java" 2nd edition, Item 7, p.27**, it gives good explanations on finalizers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your finalize method should be in the counterTest and then it will "maybe" be invoked. You never really create and instance of the "finalize" class. Therefore your finalize method never have the chance to be executed.

Here is updated code that should work as you expect:

```
class counterTest{
    public static int count;
    public counterTest(){
        count++;
    }

    protected void finalize(){
        System.out.println("Program about to terminate");
        counterTest.count--;
        System.out.println("Number of objects :" + counterTest.count);
    }
}

public class Finalize {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        counterTest obj1=new counterTest();
        System.out.println("Number of objects :" + counterTest.count);
        counterTest obj2=new counterTest();
        System.out.println("Number of objects :" + counterTest.count);
        Runtime rs=Runtime.getRuntime();
        obj1=null;
        obj2=null;
        rs.gc();
    }

}
```

It should be noted that the "finalize" methods are not meant to be overridden because they are unreliable. You never know when the Garbage collector will collect a particular object so relaying on it to close your database connections or doing other similar stuff is a No, no, no...

Comment: Thank you its working now.But why is that the finalize() method should be in the class for which we have created the objects.I mean if we have 10 classes,then is it necessary to have 10 finalize() methods in each class?

Comment: It *may* be invoked. There is nothing that guarantees GC will be invoked, let alone finalisation.

Comment: @SaiSankalp That does not make sense. *One* `finalize()` method per class.

Comment: @EJP that's what I was thinking.So we can't guarantee that gc() gets evoked every time we have kept the object references to null am I right?

Comment: @Sai finalize() methods in Java are "in practice" never really used to do anything. It is mostly the garbage collector that is using them. Nobody expects that you will override 10 finalize methods in 10 different classes. Most of the times I have see in my career someone override finalize() it is always an error.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov My answer also has a single mystery downvote. I guess there's someone who desn't like the question...

Comment: @hyde one old user on the forum once told me that it is usually pointless to ask this question "Why?", as you mostly never receive answer. I kind of agree with it , but when I think I have right, it is always a bit frustrating :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you code does not have an *instance* (AKA object) of `finalize` class. `main` method is static and does not have an instance.

But even if you did have an instance, in Java GC and calling `finalize()` methods is not very deterministic or guaranteed. It's not a destructor similar to C++. So even if you added `finalize()` method to `counterTest` class, of which you create some instances, there's no guarantee it'll get called.

If you want similar behavior as you would have with a destructor, you need to design your code around [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) pattern. Then [`AutoCloseable` interface's `close()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html#close()) takes the role of destructor.

PS. There is a *very* strong convention in Java to use so called Pascal case with class names, so your classes should be named `CounterTest` and `Finalize`.