# Runtime reports negative memory usage

Tags: java

I'm running performance tests to get execution time and memory usage. Sometimes (maybe twice or thrice out of 30) negative memory usage is reported. I would like to use Runtime so the console output has comma separated data that is easy to copy and paste into Excel.

Why do I get negative memory usage when I run a performance test?

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
long preCacheMemory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
start = System.nanoTime();

// run test

long elapsedCacheBuildTime = System.nanoTime() - start;
long postCacheMemory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
System.out.print("Cache mem (bytes) = " + (postCacheMemory - preCacheMemory) + ",");
System.out.print("Cache Build Time = " + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMicros(elapsedCacheBuildTime) + ",");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you calculate `preCacheMemory`, there might be some `garbage` in JVM which will be `collected` during `run test`.

The memory used in `run test` is less than these `garbage`.

So, when you calculate `postCacheMemory` is less than `preCacheMemory` and leads to negative memory usage.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to clear the garbage? System.gc() isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @Erik This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481178/how-to-force-garbage-collection-in-java