# After simulation, anylogic program freezes

Tags: freeze, anylogic

After running a simulation, the anylogic program (8.4) freezes most of the time. There are no errors on codes or model itself when debugging.

In the previous version, there was a button (Run Garbage Collector) on the bottom so I use that after simulation to prevent this freezing. However, i can't find the function anymore in the lastest version (8.4)

Comment: What exactly is freezing? The AnyLogic editor or the simulation itself or both? Can you show us any code that is executed at the end of simulation? Do you use any external Java libraries? Any data connections to external DB, Excel or the like?

Comment: You could try to trigger the Garbage Collection manually by code using `System.gc()` in your model. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481178/how-to-force-garbage-collection-in-java) for details on this.