# Java Garbage Collector - CMS vs G1

Tags: java, hibernate, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have a question about a garbage collector.
I have set 24GB for my Xms and Xmx, but the problem I'm facing is that I see that the full heap size is never used - the garbage collector seems to run whenever I reach 8GB of heap memory. Is it normal and I should not care much about it, or I can make it work in any other way?

I'm facing some performance issues when proceeding with 32000 of records in Hibernate/Spring and what improved the performance from 40 seconds to 6 seconds was changing the heap size from.... 512MB to 8GB and higher, but I would still want to improve the performance even further.

I saw some articles about the CMS vs G1 collectors - which of them should I use?
My app is running Java 8, if it adds any important information.

Comment: The one that performs better in real conditions for your application . Do performance testing and find out. No one else can tell you.

Comment: And if possible, you could try updating to a newer Java version which might have performance improvements or different GCs available.

Comment: Don’t ask two entirely different questions at once. The answer to your first question is, yes, it is normal that a *concurrent* garbage collector starts long before the heap is full, as otherwise, the application had to stop and wait for the garbage collector at the next allocation attempt, which would defeat the idea of performing a concurrent garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that your app does not use all the 24GB that you allocated, don't worry about it.

The moment when the garbage collector kicks in is also the concern of java and you should not worry about it. Actually, the best you can do is to suggest that garbage collector should start, but you [cannot force it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481178/how-to-force-garbage-collection-in-java).

If you want to further improve the performance then focus on your code and try to find out what can be done to make it more efficient.

You could try to upgrade to the latest version of your Hibernate provider, or even try to change it with another [JPA provider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Persistence) that might perform better in your particular scenario.

Also an upgrade to the latest java could help with performance.

Answer (score 0):

`CMS` is deprecated and [removed](https://openjdk.org/jeps/363) from the source code of jdk, there is zero support for it. Simply forget about it. `G1` is the one you want to use, but bare in mind that it is *not* the default in jdk-8. `ParallelGC` is the default one in java-8.

As to your question, yes, that is normal. Operation systems rarely trust user programs that say : "I will need that much memory to run my app", they will allocate memory to the process in a lazy fashion. There are cases where you actually want to allocate all that memory to that process though (we do that) and there is a flag for that `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch`.

When a *concurrent* GC cycle starts in `G1` (concurrent meaning *while your app threads are still running*) is decided mainly by `IHOP` (`InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent`), but that is not the only one.